# How to simplify this Makefile with loop

Tags: makefile

I have lines like these in my Makefile, can anyone suggest how to write a loop for it, or any other way to simplify it.

```
OBJS :=

obj-y :=
include cpu/Makefile
OBJS += $(patsubst %,cpu/%, $(obj-y))

obj-y :=
include drivers/Makefile
OBJS += $(patsubst %,drivers/%, $(obj-y))

obj-y :=
include lib/Makefile
OBJS += $(patsubst %,lib/%, $(obj-y))

obj-y :=
include init/Makefile
OBJS += $(patsubst %,init/%, $(obj-y))

...
```

Internal Makefiles are without any target and are used for include purpose only. For example `cpu/Makefile` is something like this:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_XYZ) += something.c
obj-$(CONFIG_ABC) += something_else.c
```

All configs are either set to `y` or `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take this in stages.

First, `patsubst` is overkill for this job; `addprefix` will do:

```
obj-y :=
include cpu/Makefile
OBJS += $(addprefix cpu/, $(obj-y))
```

Then notice that we can pull "cpu" out as a variable:

```
DIR=cpu
obj-y :=
include $(DIR)/Makefile
OBJS += $(addprefix $(DIR)/, $(obj-y))
```

Then use [`eval`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) and a [recipe template or "canned recipe"](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes):

```
define ADD_OBJECTS
obj-y :=
include $(1)/Makefile
OBJS += $$(addprefix $(1)/, $$(obj-y))
endef

$(eval $(call ADD_OBJECTS,cpu))
```

Then put that `eval` statement in a [`foreach` loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Foreach-Function):

```
$(foreach DIR,cpu drivers lib init,$(eval $(call ADD_OBJECTS,$(DIR))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Wasn't aware of recipe template or eval.